# extra table is created after creating a Redshift Materialized view

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Created a redshift materialized view (view name: lirt_cases_mv) to use external schema.  However, this extra table is created mv_tbl__lirt_cases_mv__0.  Does anyone know why this extra table is created?  Is there a way to prevent creating this extra table?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://blaqfireroundup.wordpress.com/2020/03/03/redshift-materialized-views/) article that attempts to explain the process of Materialized View refreshes under the hood in Redshift. Here is what the article suggests:

1. A stored procedure called mv_sp__house_price_mvw__0_0 is invoked
2. As part of the procedure, a backup table called mv_tbl__house_price_mvw__0__tmp is created using the materialized view query
3. A view called house_price_mvw is create/replaced using the _tmp table
4. The table mv_tbl__house_price_mvw__0 is dropped
5. The _tmp table is renamed to mv_tbl__house_price_mvw__0
6. The house_price_mvw view is create/replaced based on mv_tbl__house_price_mvw__0

If this is correct, then `mv_tbl__lirt_cases_mv__0` would be the source object responsible for create/replacing your materialized view `lirt_cases_mv`, and I don't think there would be any way around having it.

I've not verified that everything the author says in this article is true, but you can reproduce and verify for yourself by querying from `svl_statementtext` after performing a full refresh of the materialized view.